# How do we feed a file into listg in Nauty

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am trying to feed a file into the listg -o1 command in Nauty from the command prompt.

The file that I am trying to feed into the listg -o1 command is located inside the nauty folder.

I have tried a lot of different syntax and options but I cannot get it to work.

Can anybody give me an actual example with all the syntax of how to feed a file into the listg -o1 command.

I am expecting this kind of output:

Example: If you feed pp/pp-4-1 through "listg -o1" it will come out like this:
Graph 1, order 42.
1 : 22 23 24 25 26;
2 : 22 27 28 29 30;
3 : 22 31 32 33 34;
4 : 22 35 36 37 38;
5 : 22 39 40 41 42;
6 : 23 27 31 35 39;
7 : 23 28 32 36 40;
8 : 23 29 33 37 41;
9 : 23 30 34 38 42;
10 : 24 27 32 37 42;
11 : 24 28 31 38 41;
12 : 24 29 34 35 40;
13 : 24 30 33 36 39;
14 : 25 27 33 38 40;
15 : 25 28 34 37 39;
16 : 25 29 31 36 42;
17 : 25 30 32 35 41;
18 : 26 27 34 36 41;
19 : 26 28 33 35 42;
20 : 26 29 32 38 39;
21 : 26 30 31 37 40;
22 : 1 2 3 4 5;
23 : 1 6 7 8 9;
24 : 1 10 11 12 13;
25 : 1 14 15 16 17;
26 : 1 18 19 20 21;
27 : 2 6 10 14 18;
28 : 2 7 11 15 19;
29 : 2 8 12 16 20;
30 : 2 9 13 17 21;
31 : 3 6 11 16 21;
32 : 3 7 10 17 20;
33 : 3 8 13 14 19;
34 : 3 9 12 15 18;
35 : 4 6 12 17 19;
36 : 4 7 13 16 18;
37 : 4 8 10 15 21;
38 : 4 9 11 14 20;
39 : 5 6 13 15 20;
40 : 5 7 12 14 21;
41 : 5 8 11 17 18;
42 : 5 9 10 16 19;

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: " listg -o1 command in Nauty" : what langage are you using ?

Comment: @JeanMarie See https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/implement/nauty/implement.shtml, https://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/, http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut Thank you !

Comment: I am just trying to open a graph file in nauty. And then I want to use the listg -o1 command on that specific graph file. The graph file is named pp-4-1.

Comment: @JeanMarie he is using the c version of nauty